# How to order by on the basis of a column and then again ordering output using another column?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table [world] that has fields( name, population, GDP, area etc). I am able to get the table like this which is fine

```
World 

name    Total Populat.. Pop Density/KM
China   19.18            142.3
India   17.51            393.6
USA     4.47             32.4
Indonesia 3.54           132.4
Brazil    2.85           23.8
Pakistan   2.64          213.2
Nigeria   2.51           193.2
Bangladesh 2.20          1060.9
Russia    2.05            8.5
Japan     1.79           336.3
```

using the code.

```
SELECT name, 
ROUND (population/(SELECT sum(population) FROM world )* 100,2 ) as 'Total Population',
ROUND (population/area ,1) as 'Pop Density/KM'
FROM world 
ORDER BY 2 Desc LIMIT 10
```

I am trying to use this code

```
SELECT name, 
ROUND (population/(SELECT sum(population) FROM world )* 100,2 ) as 'Total Population',
ROUND (population/area ,1) as 'Pop Density/KM'
FROM world 
ORDER BY  2 DESC LIMIT 10, 3
```

so that I can have a table showing the top 10 rows by population but sort them as per 3rd column-wise. In short, I want to be able to have only these records as shown ( in the table above) but sorted on the basis on Pop Density/KM Descending wise. I am not getting the desired result

Comment: Rename your table to `countries`. Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a subquery. BUT don't use single quotes for column aliases!  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT name, 
             ROUND(population/(SELECT sum(population) FROM world) * 100, 2) as "Total Population",
             ROUND(population/area, 1) as "Pop Density/KM"
      FROM world 
      ORDER BY "Total Population" DESC
      LIMIT 10 
     ) w
ORDER BY "Pop Density/KM";
```

In MariaDB, you can also use backticks as the escape character.  Actually, I would recommend renaming the columns so they don't need to be escaped at all.

Comment: This may be a MySQL extension, but it can be further simplified:  `( SELECT ... LIMIT 10 ) ORDER BY "Pop Density/KM";`

Comment: @RickJames . . . That is interesting.  I wouldn't think to do it that way unless I were using a set operator (such as `UNION ALL`).  But it might work in most databases.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap it into another select and use double quotes as Gordon Linoff explained in his answer.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT name, 
               ROUND (population/(SELECT sum(population) FROM world )* 100,2 ) as "Total Population",
               ROUND (population/area ,1) as "Pop Density/KM"
        FROM world 
        ORDER BY 2 DESC
        LIMIT 10
      )
ORDER BY "Pop Density/KM"
```